# How to save model with relations in array source at once in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Suppose I have Post and Category models, which Post has many to many Categories. Then I want to save the following array in laravel at once:

```
$newPost = [
    'name' 'Some name of model',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'name' => 'The name of the new category without id'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'The name of the exists category'
        ]
    ]
];
```

when I use

```
$newPostInstance = new Post();
$newPostInstance->fill($newPost);
$newPostInstance->save();
```

only the name property of the post is saved without categories data.

Is there any simple way of doing that in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this when creating a single `Category` to attach with new `Post`:

```
$category = ['name' => 'The name of the new category without id'];
$newPostInstance = new Post()->fill($data);
$newPostInstance->categories()->save($category);
```

Or you may use something like this:

```
$category1 = new Category;
$category1->name = 'CatOne';
$category1->save();

$category2 = new Category;
$category2->name = 'CatTwo';
$category2->save();

$newPostInstance->categories()->sync(array($category1->id, $category2->id));
```

Check more on [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models).